# Why does only one of these tell me "Modification of a read-only value attempted"?

Tags: perl

This code runs and produces the output `abc`:

```
for(10..12){$_=sprintf"%x",$_;print}
```

But this code dies with a `Modification of a read-only value attempted at ...` error:

```
for(10,11,12){$_=sprintf"%x",$_;print}
```

Why are these constructions treated differently?

(This code also works:)

```
for(10..10,11..11,12..12){$_=sprintf"%x",$_;print}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Probably because of the "counting loop" optimization that comes into play when you `foreach` over a range. `for (1, 2, 3, 4)` actually constructs the list (1, 2, 3, 4), containing those particular readonly values, but `for (1..4)` doesn't; it just iterates from the start of the range to the end, giving `$_` each successive value in turn, and I guess nobody thought it would be worthwhile to match the behavior when you try to assign to `$_` that closely.

Comment: Indeed. The documentation says, *In the current implementation, no temporary array is created when the range operator is used as the expression in foreach loops*. So the values of `$_` are calculated dynamically and it is never aliased to a read-only constant

Answer (score 2):

Your last snippet is doing something it shouldn't. It's best demonstrated with the following code:

```
for (1..2) {
   for (1..3, 5..7) {
      print $_++;
   }
   print "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
123567
234678
```

[RT#3105](https://rt.perl.org/rt3/Ticket/Display.html?id=3105)

---

As far as I'm concerned, there are three kinds of for loops:

- "C-style" (`for (my $i=1; $i<4; ++$i)`)
- Iterating (`for my $i (1,2,3)`)
- Counting (`for my $i (1..3)`)